# Using a BTHomeHub as a wireless booster

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I currently have a BT HomeHub downstairs but the wireless signal isnt strong enough on the second floor. I have an old BT HomeHub from the previous contract that I wanted to set up upstairs. I currently have an ethernet cable leading up into the old router. I then took my laptop and plugged it into the old router in hopes of configuring it but when I cannot reach api.home which is the address of the router. I cannot connect to the router wirelessly either since the password was changed and I'd have to change it through config. At this point I am completely stumped, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry if I appear thick, but are you trying to set up the second hub as a wireless repeater or as a network hub?